# Update fields with same name in a Mongo Collection

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My question is, I have a collection like this:

```
"cost_price" : 79.9,
"list_price" : 189.9,
"sale_price" : 189.9,
"integrations" : {
    "erp" : {
        "mbm" : {
            "cost_price" : 79.9,
            "list_price" : 189.9,
            "sale_price" : 189.9
        },
        "linx" : {
            "cost_price" : 79.9,
            "list_price" : 189.9,
            "sale_price" : 200.1
        }
    },
    "marketplace" : {
        "netshoes" : {
            "list_price" : 189.9,
            "sale_price" : 199.9
        }
    },
    "ecommerce" : {
        "vtex" : {
            "list_price" : 189.9,
            "sale_price" : 189.9
        },
        "magento" : {
            "list_price" : 189.9,
            "sale_price" : 189.9
        }
    }
}
```

How can I update all fields named 'list_price' within this collection in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

May be help you.

```
db.products.updateMany({}, {
 $rename: {
    "list_price": "new_name",
    "integrations.erp.mbm.list_price": "new_name",
    "integrations.erp.linx.list_price": "new_name",
    "integrations.erp.linx.list_price": "new_name",
    "integrations.marketplace.netshoes.list_price": "new_name",
    "integrations.ecommerce.vtex.list_price": "new_name",
    "integrations.ecommerce.magento.list_price": "new_name"        
 }})
```

Comment: Indeed, but the thing is, whenever I add another integration I'll have to manually add another line on it. That's my problem, making it generic.